# PHPUnit code coverage skips certain lines

Tags: php, phpunit

For some reason php unit's code coverage feature is skipping certain lines.  I have played around with it a fair amount, and if I just `echo ($hydrationData['partnerNames']);`, coverage works just fine. I have tried running the tests with `--verbose` and `--debug`, but no information is emitted.  I have tried this with PHPUnit versions 4.0 and 4.4.

```
    if(isset($hydrationData['partnerNames'])) {

        // this line will be marked as not covered
        unset($hydrationData['partnerNames']); 

        // got here will be printed during unit test and this line marked as covered
        echo('got here'); 

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you found a [quirk](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.edge-cases) in either PHP's Zend Engine (likely) or Xdebug (less likely).

There is nothing we can do about this in PHP_CodeCoverage or PHPUnit.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I appreciate your work on the project!